# NameError: free variable 'addcontact' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Tags: python-3.x, scope, nameerror

please be kind with my n00b question but it is driving me crazy and googling it didn't help much unfortunately.

I am trying to write a simple phonebook script using an empty dictionary as a learning exercise but as I am self taught there is no one else to turn to.

So here's what's happening,
I want to write a menu function that includes subfunctions for adding, deleting and editing {name:number} contacts

it is mostly working except for when I try to call the add function from within the edit

this is part of the menu code including the add routine

```
def menu():
        selection = (int(input("""1:View phonebook
    2:Add contact
    3:Delete contact
    4:Search for a contact and if necessary edit it
    5:Save and Exit
    
    What would you like to to?""")))
    
        if selection == 1:
            if len(phonebook)== 0:
                print("Phonebook is empty, please add a contact first.")
                loop = input("Press Enter to continue ...")
                menu()
            else:
                print(phonebook)
                loop = input("Press Enter to continue ...")
                menu()
    
        elif selection == 2:
            def addcontact():
                first = (str(input("First name: ")))
                last = (str(input("Last name: ")))
                num = (str(input("Number? ")))
                phonebook.update({last + " " + first: num})
                loop = input("Contact saved, press Enter to continue.")
                menu()
                
                (other stuff...)

menu()
```

and this is the update subroutine that's giving me trouble

```
    elif selection == 4:
    def search_and_edit():
        search = (str(input("Please type the exact name of the contact you are looking for: ")))
        if search in phonebook.keys():
            print("Name: ", search, "Number: ", phonebook[search])
            edit = (str(input("Do you wish to edit this contact? Y/N")))
            if edit == "N" or edit == "n":
                menu()
            if edit == "Y" or edit == "y":
                phonebook.pop(search)
                addcontact()
        else:
            print("Contact not found.")

        loop = input("Press Enter to continue.")
        menu()
```

and this is the error message from PyCharm

```
File "C:\Users\Derek\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\phonebook\phonebook.py", line 78, in search_and_edit
addcontact()
NameError: free variable 'addcontact' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
    
Process finished with exit code 1
```

what am I doing wrong here? the other callbacks work fine ("loop" callbacks to return to the main menu for example) but the addcontact() one fails with a variable error message even though it's a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome aboard. The issue boils down to the `addcontact` being defined within the scope of a conditional (`if...elif...else`) and as a result not visible to `search_and_edit` which is defined in a different and mutually exclusive branch. So, when you chose 4, the program hadn't really entered 2 and the `addcontact` had not been "created" yet.

If you wish to make a function available at multiple places, then define it where it would in scope for all the callers.

Comment: thank you for getting back to me so soon
I understand what you are saying, it explains perfectly why the `menu()` callbacks work when the `addcontact()` doesn't what I don't get is how am I supposed to do that without having it run when it is not supposed to. Should I be using classes to do this? (I haven't even gotten that far, I have no idea how they work) Does this mean I need to study more? Because I have a feeling that this is exactly where this is going... Anyway, thank you, I will be accepting the answer and close this!

Comment: While classes can make this use-case easier to handle, there is a way to make your code work with only a few modifications. For example, you could define `addcontact` outside `menu` (but within the same script), so that it will be visible to every branch of the conditional. IMPORTANT: I can't see where you've defined `phonebook`, but given that it's used both within `addcontact` and `menu`, it must be defined outside these functions as well for the modified program to work.

Comment: code is here

https://github.com/Giorgos-vr/pb-app/blob/main/phonebook.py

(in this version I have removed the reference and replaced the steps)
It's for a self-learn assignment, the assignment only asks for a simple dictionary script to add and display `{key:value}` pairs, the menu and the conditionals were all my idea to take it a step further...

Comment: So, it looks like the `phonebook` is where it needs to be. Move the `addcontact` (and any other function that's called from more than one branch) to outside `menu`. In fact, if a functionality is not required outside more than one branch, you can use the code as is without wrapping it in a function. (e.g. `search_and_edit`.) The idea behind a function is to prevent yourself from repeating the same piece of code in multiple places. When you have the time, give this article a read to understand the ideas involved better: https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/

Comment: I knew the answer would be "keep reading" and there seems to be quite a lot I need to go through. Thank you! :)